# Utilizar Tag <head> <body> em projetos Angular

Tags: html, angular, html-tags

Estou estudando Angular e fiquei com uma duvida ref. a utilização das tags `<head>` e `<body>`

Por exemplo, em um arquivo html faria:

```
<head>
    <title>{{ tittle }}</title>
</head>
<body>
        <p>teste</p>
</body>
```

Teria necessidade da utilização dessas tags em projetos angular?

Comment: Não sei onde está aprendendo e qual o nível de aprendizado que está, mas, quando cria um projeto Angular, o único arquivo Html que terá as tags **`head`** e **`body`** é o **index.html** dentro da pasta padrão **`src`**. Ele serve basicamente para indexar a aplicação no browser, mas, para fins de desenvolvimento ele praticamente não é utilizado.

Comment: LeAndrade, ao criar um novo component utilizando a ferramenta angular cli, é automaticamente criado um novo arquivo .html, minha duvida é, ha necessidade de incluir essas tags nesses novos arquivos?

Comment: Não precisa não

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você cria um projeto em Angular, por padrão dentro da pasta `src` tem um arquivo chamado `index.html`. Este arquivo contém basicamente a estrutura que você citou, `head`, `body` e alguns outros itens. Este arquivo será entregue toda vez que o navegador acessar sua aplicação.

Dentro deste arquivo há mais uma tag importante, normalmente chamada `app-root` (pode ser alterada) que é onde o Angular irá criar todo o visual e irá gerenciar (criar DOM, adicionar eventos, etc) toda a aplicação no lado do cliente utilizando JavaScript.

Então como sua aplicação entregará um único arquivo com a estrutura básica de uma página HTML, para alterar por exemplo o `title`, você terá que recorrer as funções que o Angular dispõe. Para fazer esta alteração de `title` você terá que recorrer a classe `Title` em `@angular/platform-browser`.

Sendo assim você não precisa se preocupar tanto com o `head` e `body` visto que eles ficarão em um único arquivo. Minha sugestão é se preocupar em como o Angular funciona: https://angular.io/guide/architecture